# Finding equation, given solutions to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble determining a homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients that have the following solutions: $1$, $x$, $e^{-3x}$, $e^{-5x}\cos(4x)$, $\sin(3x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to rewrite your solutions as $$e^{0x}$$ $$xe^{0x}$$ $$e^{-3x}$$ $$e^{(-5+4i)x}+e^{(-5-4i)x}$$ $$e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}.$$
Note that the last solutions are actually two solutions each, added together. Thus, we have seven solutions. This calls for a seventh-order differential equation: $$c_1y+c_2y^{(2)}+c_3y^{(3)}+c_4y^{(4)}+c_5y^{(5)}+c_6y^{(6)}+c_7y^{7)}.$$ Each of the solutions (except one, we'll get to that) is of the form $e^{kx}$ for some $k$. Recall that the values of $k$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial:
$$c_1r+c_2r^2+c_3r^2+c_4r^4+c_5r^5+c_6r^6+c_7r^7.$$
Thus, we just choose the characteristic polynomial to be $$r^2(r+3)(r-(-5+4i))(r-(-5-4i))(r-3i)(r+3i).$$ Expand this out to find the coefficients $c_1,...,c_7$ to build your ODE. Two of the roots are zero. Recall that whenever a root $k$ is repeated twice, $e^{kx}$ is a solution, and $xe^{kx}$ is a solution. This accounts for the form of the first two solutions.